# Dictionary of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Im trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries in python. I have a nested for loop which looks like this

```
frequencyLomb = {}
for J in range(1,81,4):
  n_items = take(dataDays.values(),J-1,J+3)
  for K in range(1,5):
    temp_time=n_items[K-1][0]
    temp_flux=n_items[K-1][1]
    mean_temp_flux=np.mean(temp_flux)

    temp_flux_final=temp_flux-mean_temp_flux
    # frequencyLomb[J][K] = freq_grid(temp_time)   want something like this
```

*n_items* is a 4 element list with indexes 0 to 3 and in every one of these is a two element list with indexes 0 and 1. Now I want to create a dictionary of dictionaries which will save the value of frequencyLomb in way so that the Key name will be the variable J and the items will be added from the inner for loop so the final product will look like this:

```
frequencyLomb= {1: {1: 'somevalue1', 2: 'somevalue1', 3: 'somevalue1', 4: 'somevalue1', 5: 'somevalue1'},
      5: {1: 'somevalue1',....}}
```

etc. up to Key number 80

P.S.: The function *freq_grid* just creates an array of floats and the function *take* takes the values from dictionary dataDays(dictionary of lists) with keys number J-1 up to values with key J+3

Thanks. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for `defaultdict` from collections in the standard library. Creating a `defaultdict` with `dict` as default factory will enable you to write to `frequencyLomb[J][K]` without first creating dict at `frequencyLomb[J]`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

frequencyLomb = defaultdict(dict)

for J in range(1, 81, 4):
  n_items = take(dataDays.values(), J - 1, J + 3)
  for K in range(1,5):
    temp_time=n_items[K-1][0]
    temp_flux=n_items[K-1][1]
    mean_temp_flux=np.mean(temp_flux)

    temp_flux_final=temp_flux-mean_temp_flux
    frequencyLomb[J][K] = freq_grid(temp_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if j not in frequencyLomb: #Then try frequencyLomb[J] = {} and then frequncyLomb[J][K] = Your Value


else: #Then directly add your value to the inner dictionary.
```